# Cannot read findById of underfined in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I call the function, I getting
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findById' of undefined

Any help will be really appreciated

Here is the code.

```
exports.getProductSellingPrice = async (productId) => {
  const product = await Product.findById(productId).select("sellingPrice -_id");
  return Number(product.sellingPrice);
};
```

Using the intellisense it can show that the Product is imported well [image]

However, when I run the code I am getting the error

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'findById' of undefined

      31 |
      32 | exports.getProductSellingPrice = async (productId) => {
    > 33 |   const product = await Product.findById(productId).select("sellingPrice -_id");
         |                                 ^
      34 |   return Number(product.sellingPrice);
      35 | };
      36 |

      at Object.findById [as getProductSellingPrice] (src/database/services/user.js:33:33)
      at model.getProductSellingPrice [as addProductsToCart] (src/database/models/user.js:48:43)
      at Object.addProductsToCart (tests/models/user.test.js:94:24)
          at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: How do you initialize `Product`?

Comment: Yes. I have intialized the product since I have automated tests. Intialized or not, the Product.findById should work. If the product is not initialized return null

Comment: your error literally says  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'findById' of undefined` which means that `Product` schema is undefined and that's why it doesn't have `findById` property

Comment: I have defined the Product Model, Look at the screenshot that I have attached.

Comment: That is just typing of `Product` please provide your implementation of usage. The problem is that `Product` is undefined. It says so in your error

Comment: I have resolved the problem by moving the getProductSellingPrice function  in another source file

Comment: I don't know why it woudn't work in the current file